# How to use static folder but also use routing in Express?

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm having a major issue with Routing in Express.

In my project, there is a folder `/public`.

Inside `/folder` I have some other folders like

```
- public
     |- user
     |- common
```

Initially, the only way pages were served by my Node.js server was through `res.sendFile(../..)`. The problem was that the `.js` files and `.css` files did not know where to go.

So I added

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But now the problem is, if I try to visit `/user` what happens is, that the **static** version of the `index.html` file in that folder is returned, and my route defined in the node app is *ignored!*

This route - and most importantly the auth middleware is never touched!

How do I reconcile the need to serve files from a static folder, but also may have routes of the same name that I want to control more closely?

```
app.use('/user', userauth, userRoutes);
```

Comment: Can you check from your browser's network request tool that the request is actually "GET /user" and not "GET /user/index.html". Or if you have a logger on serverside that displays request logs on console

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/user` is some sort of API I don't think express.static was intended to be used that way. I think the best solution would be to use different routes. You could add something like /api/ to the beginning of all your routes or make sure your static files are organized under /css, /js, /partials, etc.

If you absolutely must support /user for static files AND your api calls you will need to ditch express.static and use something like the Accept header with custom middleware that determines what the browser is asking for. Depending on the scenario this may get complicated to support all the variables. A simple example would be something like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){ 
    // check Accept header to make sure its a JSON request
    if(req.accepts('application/json') && !req.accepts('html')) {

        // JSON request so forward request on to the next middleware(eventually hitting the route)
        return next();
    }

    // NOT a JSON request so lets serve up the file if it exists...

    // TODO use req.path to check if file exists - if not 404 - will also need to map paths 
    // to /users to check for /users/index.html if you need to support that
    var fileExists = false;

    return fileExists ? res.sendFile('...') || res.status(404).send('Not Found');
});
```

You would have to make sure when the client calls `/users` it sets the Accept header to `application/json`. Most client side frameworks have a way to do this for all AJAX requests.

Comment: There must be a simple way no? All websites have certain areas that are off limits unless you are logged in. In my case I want `/user` to be blocked off unless user is authenticated. But even so, I want all the `css`, `js`, etc to be accessible